# Как в Hilt прокинуть runtime зависимость?

Tags: android, retrofit2, di

Подскажите, как быть, я получаю baseUrl для ретрофита одним запросом, а после хочу 'сказать Hilt', вот тебе Url для этой зависимости, создавай теперь.

Если не очень понятно объяснил, то могу добавить пример.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html

Comment: Assisted Injection не совсем подходит, мне нужно, чтобы Hilt создавал UseCase <- Repository <- SomeApi <- Retrofit <- ...

Зависимость нужно предоставить в Retrofit в этом графе, чтобы я мог получать корректный use case. И я же всё-таки про Hilt-way спрашиваю.